# Deployment of saleor using Dockerfile fails

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, dockerfile, saleor

I was trying to deploy my customized [Saleor](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor-storefront) in DigitalOcean droplet using Dockerfile. For production environment Dockerfile is

```sh
FROM node:10 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG API_URI
ENV API_URI ${API_URI:-http://localhost:8000/graphql/}
RUN API_URI=${API_URI} npm run build

FROM nginx:stable
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /app/
```

For developement environment Dockerfile.dev is

```sh
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ARG APP_MOUNT_URI
ARG API_URI
ARG STATIC_URL
ENV API_URI ${API_URI:-http://localhost:8000/graphql/}
ENV APP_MOUNT_URI ${APP_MOUNT_URI:-/dashboard/}
ENV STATIC_URL ${STATIC_URL:-/dashboard/}

EXPOSE 9000
CMD npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0
```

I can deploy using Dockerfile.dev but can't deploy using Dockerfile for production. Ended up with the following errors

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! saleor-site@2.10.4 build: `webpack -p`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the saleor-site@2.10.4 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-23T18_40_53_645Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'storefront' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c API_URI=${API_URI} npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: The actual interesting error is above what you show.  Put aside Docker for the moment; in the Node environment you use for day-to-day development, if you `rm -rf node_modules; npm install; npm run build`, does it work?

Comment: @DavidMaze getting same error. So the problem is with my packages not with docker